# PHP script not returning query, but the MySql query works

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

My ultimate goal is to have a js script return the results of a PHP query as json so I can do nefarious things with it.

I have the MySql query I want to use and it is definitely working when I test it in Workbench, but when I try it in the PHP script, nothing gets returned. The current query in PHP is just a placeholder one to test out the data interchange.

I manually put in something to the array (searchResults) and that gets return but NOTHING comes from the PHP script when it is executed.

I also understand this may not be the most secure or efficient code, I just want to get it working at this point.

```
<?php
    // Include your database creds and login to the db
    require_once 'login_karavites.php';
    $db = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

    // Handle the input/request.
    $searchString_UNSAFE = $_POST['eName']; // change that, obviously

    // Bare minimum sanitation to prevent injection.
    $searchString = $db->escape_string($searchString_UNSAFE);

    // Construct the SQL query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Halls` WHERE hall_name = 'Rose Ballroom'";

    // Do the database lookup.
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    // Create empty array to hold our results (to be sent back to the browser).
    $searchResults = array();
    $searchResults[]="wow";
    // If we had results, put them into that array
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        // This loop will retrieve every row from that result set
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            // From each row, just take the 'event_name' field.
            $searchResults[] = $row['hall_name'];

        }

    }

    // Done with the db, now we just have to send the results back to the browser.
    $db->close();

    // Send the correct content-type header.
    // This ensures that jQuery automatically converts the response into an 
    // array or object, rather than just treating it like a block of text.
    // Must be the FIRST thing the PHP script outputs, or it will choke.
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    // Output the data.
    echo json_encode($searchResults);

?>
```

The js script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // All this stuff runs as soon as the page is fully loaded

    // Attach a function to the Submit action on #eventForm
    $('#eventForm').submit(function() {

        // Submit the form via AJAX
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({

            // Attach a function to the "the PHP script returned some results" event
            success: function(response, status, xhr, $form){
                // I am assuming that this is your data format, for example:
                // { "searchResults": [ "result1", "result2", "result3" ] }
                // I am also assuming that you want your results in div#results
                $('div#results').html(""); // Clear it out of anything that's already there.
                console.log(response);
                for (i in response['searchResults']) {
                    $('div#results').append( response['searchResults'][i] );
                }
            },

            // Give up if PHP doesn't answer in 3 seconds
            timeout: 3000,

            // Path to the PHP file we want to send this to
            url: 'phpdata/eventsData.php'
        });

        // Make sure the browser does NOT proceed to submit the form again,
        // the old fashioned way (full page reload).
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you try to call your php script directly using your browser? Can you see anything? If the answer are 'yes' and 'no', did you try to dump the content of $searchResults prior to set headers?

Comment: When I try and call it directly, I still only get that one line. It is also the same thing if I comment out the setHeaders line.

Comment: You have unused variable `$searchString`

Comment: Perhaps is just for your testing purpose, but do you have any results in your db for this query?

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Halls` WHERE hall_name = 'Rose Ballroom'";

And what is exactly 'that one line'?

Comment: comment this `$searchResults[]="wow";`

Comment: I get a successful output from the query.

The search string will contain the actual variable from the form once I get it working.

Comment: I believe you need to set dataType: 'json'

Answer (score 0):

What part of my problem was:

- I stupidly never set the form-method in the original form so the POST wasn't actually going through.
- I had set up the MySql connection wrong in the PHP file.

My own notes, MAKE SURE YOU CHECK ALL THE SETTINGS.